# Word/Writer — Bible-like two column layout

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, openoffice, openoffice-writer

Is there a way to create a "standard" bible-like layout in Microsoft Word or OpenOffice Writer without using tables?

It should be a two column layout but the columns are not "global":

```
Paragraph 1 text starts here | ..................
............................ | .....and ends here!

--- A title or some empty space here ---

Paragraph 2 text starts here | ..................
............................ | .....and ends here!
```

Comment: you need to put continuous section breaks between each part you want to be separated. (= select each paragraph and set column settings separately instead of selecting the whole document at once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## LibreOffice Writer

1. Click **Insert** > **Section**
2. Select **Columns** tab
3. Set the amount of columns to 2

This section will appear now as you like and if you go outside of it, you will stay to the normal layout, so you will have to insert or copy this section every time you want the 2 column layout.

## Microsoft Word

### The paragraphs

1. Move the cursor to the end of your paragraph.
2. Switch to the **Layout** ribbon
3. Choose **Columns** > **Two**
4. Choose **Breaks** > **Contentious**

### The headline

1. Switch to the **Layout** ribbon
2. Choose **Columns** > **One**